# Process sssd_kcm takes a lot of CPU, is this safe to disable?

Tags: centos, cpu-usage, kerberos, centos-8

On a production server (internal network), I see the process `sssd_kcm` taking a lot of CPU usage (it is basically always on top in `top`). I understand this process handles Kerberos caching. I have not set up Kerberos (that I know of) on this machine, so I was wondering if it safe to disable this service, or would other parts be negatively affected?

The machine is running CentOS8 with an WebApp (PHP/Apache) and some proprietary software packages.

Comment: If you do `klist` (regardless of whether you have Kerberos tickets or not), does its output show it using KCM or does it use something else? Does your /etc/krb5.conf mention KCM? What does `strace -f -p <pid>` show the service doing)

Comment: This [post](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1645624#c113) sees a problem between GOA and KCM. Does it pertain to your problem?

Comment: @u1686_grawity `klist` is not installed (neither on the server, not on my test machine).

Comment: @harrymc Gnome is not running on that machine (or X for that matter).

Answer (score 0):

KCM is an optional alternative ticket cache; in general, it's safe to disable it as long as Kerberos is configured to use some other cache type as default. (The default default is a plain file-based cache in /tmp, though there are several other options – the default_ccache is defined in `/etc/krb5.conf`.)

Still, I would strongly recommend investigating the actual cause of the 100% CPU usage **before** trying to disable the service outright. Otherwise, it might be that whatever was (presumably) hammering KCM in a loop might just keep reading the file-based cache in an equally CPU-consuming loop... (Besides, if you don't have Kerberos, then why is something attempting to use Kerberos?)

Comment: I have installed a basic install of CentOS 8 Stream on this machine. I have never done anything with Kerberos in my life. So, this should all be defaults and have no problems. I did find that the CPU usage of `sssd_kcm` goes down with the usage of `httpd`, so I reckon it is something there.

Comment: The `default_ccache_name` is set to `KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}`, whatever that is ...